# ¿como agrego safe args a mi proyecto?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle

me podrían ayudar?

estoy tratando de implementar safe args a mi proyecto, ya aplique los build.gradle necesarios que son:

```
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigationVersion"
```

y

```
    apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
```

la documentación dice que luego de sincronizar, el proyecto creara clases NavDirection para cada fragment pero esto no ocurre por lo tanto me da error el codigo.

Answer (score 1):

Si estas usando Kotlin, realiza lo que indica la documentaciòn debes agregar en tu `build.gradle` del proyecto:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5"
    }
}
```

y dentro de `app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
```

pero es demasiado importante que dentro de tu archivo  gradle.properties tengas definido:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Revisa la documentaciòn en español

[Cómo pasar datos entre destinos](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data)